# javascript form submitting to wrong target second time

Tags: javascript, iframe, form-submit

I have a form I am submitting with `form.submit()` to a hidden iframe.  I then take the result and process the data.

If the result fails (validation errors) then I display an error in a div tag.

The problem I have is that if you press the submit button again the form submits to a new tab.

I tried `form.reset();  //` just resets the form.

I have tried resetting the target of the form to the hidden iframe again but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Can you please show the relevant html and JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this a long time back. 
The trick was to set the target of the form to hidden iframe using html and not JS. What I mean is, you should do:

```
formContainer.html("<form target='iframe_name' .... />");
```

However,

```
get_form_by_id.setAttribute("target","iframe_name")
```

didn't provide the desired result.
(There shouldn't be a reason for it, however speaking from experience, I faced this issue when designing an IE compatible website and this was the solution that worked).

Comment: Thank you.  I figured out my problem.  There was an error being thrown and code execution would stop.  Also, the form was being added to an existing page after the page load was complete.  The target needs to be modified via javascript prior to inserting the form onto the page.  I got it working but strangely enough there were never errors thrown like they should have been. Thanks!